# Oracle 11g - Share Sys_Context values across pool connection by user_id

Tags: database, spring, oracle, plsql

Can anyone provide a good enough example of shared `Sys_Context` in action using

`Dbms_Session.Set_Identifier(user_id)`

I want to be able to access some sys context attribute from a different connection after the user has successfully signed in.

---

**My scenario**:

*Spring Boot 2.0.6 Connects to Oralce 11g using **HikariCP connection pool***

**The Procedure**

1. User accesses a login page
2. Signs-in -> `user_id` is set `Dbms_Session.Set_Context('ENV', USER_ID, user_id)`
3. User access some resource (e.g. Accounts) -> `Sys_Context('ENV', user_id)` returns `Null`

`Sys_Context('ENV', user_id)` returns Null because the resource is accesses db via a different connection, hence no user_id in **CURRENT** context.

---

This Oracle documentation claims it is possible: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG79745

As these guides below:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_session
https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/network.102/b14266/apdvcntx.htm

If this is not possible please tell what exactly `Dbms_Session.Set_Identifier(user_id)` is used for because I find these docs quite obscure and I couldn't replicate any examples that they show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The context must be created with the `GLOBALLY ACCESSIBLE` option, e.g.

   ```
   create context ENV using scott.security_pkg accessed globally;
   ```
2. `dbms_session.set_context` is called with the session ID (within `scott.security_pkg`) e.g.

   ```
   dbms_session.set_context(
     namespace => 'ENV',
     attribute => 'user_id',
     value     => 'jane',
     client_id => '12345');
   ```
3. `dbms_session.set_identifier` must be called with the user's session ID in each session, e.g.

   ```
   dbms_session.set_identifier(client_id=>'12345');
   ```
4. Now, you can get the value for the attribute using `sys_context`, e.g.

   ```
   sys_context('ENV','user_id')
   ```

This is just an example using `user_id` as the name for an attribute you wish to store. The important bit is `client_id` which uniquely identifies a user's session.

Comment: Thanks, the key point is to create a **GLOBALLY ACCESSIBLE** context and call `dbms_session.set_identifier` before every `datasource.getConnection()` (AOP or manually). I have tested with 2 PLSQL Developer (IDEA) connections. Contexts are indeed accessible from different sessions and show up in `select * from global_context`